# Unable to configure DD-WRT SNMP monitoring with Zabbix

Tags: snmp, dd-wrt

Installed Zabbix on Ubuntu but not sure what setting I missed. Base on my concept, I would like to using SNMP to monitoring DD-WRT router which it using SNMP service.

I did enable to SNMP service at DD-WRT router page. And also created a host at Zabbix with included DD-WRT template. After I done it I still unable to get any connection/information at Zabbix which mean the router doesn't communicate with Zabbix.

The above picture is my DD-WRT's SNMP configuration.

[image]

Also this is the Zabbix configuration which I have created the service to monitoring my DD-WRT router.

[image]

Comment: Can you post the list of items for your DD-WRT host?

Comment: @StephenKing This is the item list in my DD-WRT host, which it have 122 items.

(http://imageshack.us/a/img703/7182/azsu.png)
(http://imageshack.us/a/img703/7182/azsu.png)
(http://imageshack.us/a/img844/7237/2zdn.png)

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities:

- Install zabbix-agent on the DD-WRT router
- Do not use the DD-WRT template, but either use an SNMP template or create your custom items

All your items are of type `Zabbix Agent`. This requires that agent to run on the device. No data will be pulled by SNMP with this config.

Comment: I did research on the `Zabbix Agent` on `DD-WRT` seem the `atheros chipset` doesn't support the Zabbix Agent, can I using the default SNMP function in DD-WRT to monitoring by using the Zabbix?

Comment: Where did you find that information? Did you try to compile the agent from source? Here's a tutorial: http://www.diegolima.org/wordpress/?p=407

Comment: And yes.. that's the second choice I mentioned: Add the Host in Zabbix using the `Template_SNMPv2_Device`. You can also add additional SNMP items that are exposed by the router's MIB, but not in the Template.

Comment: What I did rightnow is my currently my router IP is `192.168.1.1` and I create a host at Zabbix also put the `SNMP interfaces` as `191.168.1.1`. I were follow this `http://projectdaenney.org/blog/2012/10/14/zabbix-baby-steps-part-1/` to configure the setting. After I done this basic setting, I create a host to monitoring my router which I have add the `Template SNMP Generic` as my template`., but I still unable to monitoring my router which is come wiht `Timeout while connecting to "192.168.1.1:161`.

Comment: Just to make sure: You've activated the SNMP agent and can also connect to it through an SNMP browser on your PC? Community names (public/private) match?
What's not clear to me is "I create a host... After I done this basic setting, I create a host.." - you're not creating two hosts, aren't you?